# Using prefetch_related for reducing queries overhead

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    #code
```

views.py

```
class PostList(ListView):
     model = Post
     def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Post.objects.all().\
         select_related('category')
```

But for my main page i need further all categories for the navbar. What the best approach to add categories to get_queryset()?

I tried to use prefetch_related.

```
post = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('category')
```

but i don't understand how to fetch all categories.

Is it correct solution?

```
class PostList(ListView):
     def get_queryset(self):
         p = Post.objects.all().\
         select_related('category') #like tag for each post
         p.categories = Category.objects.all() #all categories for navbar 
         return p
```

Or Django has own methods for  this task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what this has to do with either select_related or prefetch_related. Neither of those will help in getting categories that are not related to your posts: as their names imply, they are to do with getting related items, not unrelated ones.

If you need all the categories, you should simply do `Category.objects.all()`.

Comment: For example, in template for each post i need category label (like red "cars" label in this template http://wp.color-theme.com/crossroad/carbon-and-candy-by-japan-tuning-espana/) And i need all categories for navbar part of template. If i understood you right this mean in get_queryset i should use select_related for each post and separately  Category.objects.all